# Error compiling an Angular2 application

Tags: angular, typescript

I am seeing some compiling errors while building my (basic) app. If I do `npm start` the app starts just fine and there is no error displayed. However if I do `ng build --prod` the command spits 3 error messages as follows:

```
ERROR in ng:///clarity-seed/src/app/app.component.html (103,54): Property 'gradient' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.

ERROR in /clarity-seed/src/$$_gendir/app/app.component.ngfactory.ts (845,36): Property 'pageviews' does not exist on type '{}'.

ERROR in ng:///clarity-seed/src/app/app.component.html (120,95): Property 'hostname' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

The `pageviews` and `hostname` variable are all contained inside the `app.component.ts` which I am copying/pasting here below. I suspect this is a problem with how I declare/use such variables in the file.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()

@Component({
    selector: 'yelb',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private router: Router,
                private http:  Http
               ) {}

  votes: any[] = [];
  stats = {};
  ngOnInit(){this.getvotes(); this.getstats()}

  public appserver = `http://localhost:4567`;

  view: any[] = [700, 200];

  hostname = "mio host"

  pageviews = 3

  colorScheme = {
    domain: ['#5AA454', '#A10A28', '#C7B42C', '#AAAAAA']
  };

    getvotes(): void {
    const url = `${this.appserver}/getvotes`;
    this.http.get(url)
                .map((res: Response) => res.json())
                .subscribe(res => {console.log(res); this.votes = res})                
    }

    getstats(): void {
    const url = `${this.appserver}/getstats`;
    this.http.get(url)
                .map((res: Response) => res.json())
                .subscribe(res => {console.log(res, res.hostname, res.pageviews); this.stats = res})                
    }

    vote(restaurant: string): void {
    const url = `${this.appserver}/${restaurant}`;
    this.http.get(url)
                .map((res: Response) => res.json())
                .subscribe(res => {console.log(res)});    
    this.getvotes()
    }
}
```

However `gradient` is something I am using inside the html file (`app.component.html`) and that leverages an external library.

This is a snippet of the portion of `app.component.html` where `gradient`is used.

Again I suspect that `gradient` is the only thing not being properly declared where it should be:

```
<div class="col-xs">
    <ngx-charts-advanced-pie-chart [view]="view" [scheme]="colorScheme" [results]="votes" [gradient]="gradient">
    </ngx-charts-advanced-pie-chart>
</div>
```

Any hint re how I can get rid of those error messages? Sure thing this piece of code can go through a substantial optimization but for now I would just need to compile with no errors.

Thanks!

UPDATE #1: I have fixed the issue with the `gradient` variable by adding `gradient: boolean;`. I have just figured that the wrong `hostname` reference as described in the errors at compile time is coming from the html file (not from the ts file). These are the code snippet of how/when I reference `hostname` and `pageviews` in the `app.component.html` file:

```
<li class="list-group-item">
       <a target="_blank">Container: <b><u>{{stats.hostname}}</u></b></a>
</li>
```

and:

```
<li class="list-group-item">
       <a target="_blank">Number of page views so far: <b><u>{{stats.pageviews}}</u></b></a>
</li>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `hostname = "mio host"` with `hostname : string = "mio host"`?

Comment: @Darshita yeah I tried that. I am getting the exact same error.

Comment: I seem to have fixed the problem with the `gradient` variable by adding the following line to the application file: `gradient: boolean;`. Still trying to figure out how to properly declare the `pageviews` and `hostname` variable.

Comment: The problem seems to lie somewhere in between how I have declared `stats` in the application file i.e. `stats = {};` and how I am calling `pageviews` and `hostname` in the html file i.e. `{{stats.pageviews}}` and `{{stats.hostname}}`. Can't figure out how to fix it though.

Comment: will it helpful to not assign value to `hostname`?You have assigned value to `hostname` manually.Just declare it with appropriate datatype.

Comment: @Darshita  Actually, I have tried to remove completely `hostname = "mio host"` and "pageviews = 3` and I get the same error. The problem is that the error message seems to originate from the html file when I reference `{{stats.hostname}}`. Hence I thought a mismatch between how I declared `stats` in the app file and how I am calling it from the html file.

Comment: Though you are using it in html file , try declaring `hostname` like `gradient: boolean` , as you are using it as a variable.

Comment: So it looks like that in order for it to compile properly I need to set `hostname: any;` `pageviews: any;` as well as `stats: any;`. If I don't set `stats` to `any` it won't compile. The problem with this setup is that now when I load the page the console spits a few error messages such `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'pageviews' of undefined `. For whatever reasons it only complains about `pageviews` and not `hostname` (which I use similarly throughout the html).

Comment: To declare `hostname: any;` in such a way is required while doing AOT.When you compile it without AOT then no need of it as it is array's property, so we can directly use it in html file.